# Spring Boot style edition in Geoserver by Rest Api

Tags: spring-boot, rest, post, geoserver, http-status-code-400

Could You please help me to edit styles in geoserver by POST method? I am in trouble with this and I am stuck in one place. When I run this code and go to http://localhost:8010/styles/point on the page and I have Whitelabel error and in postman I have an error 400 Bad Request

```
public class StyleRequest {
    private String fill = "#042041";
    private String stroke = "#040001";

    public String getFill() {
        return fill;
    }

    public void setFill(String fill) {
        this.fill = fill;
    }

    public String getStroke() {
        return stroke;
    }

    public void setStroke(String stroke) {
        this.stroke = stroke;
    }
}
```

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/styles")
public class StyleController {

    private GeoServerStyleService styleService;

    @Autowired
    public StyleController(GeoServerStyleService styleService) {
        this.styleService = styleService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> editStyle(@PathVariable String name, @RequestBody StyleRequest styleRequest) {
        styleService.editStyle(name, styleRequest.getFill(), styleRequest.getStroke());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@Service
public class GeoServerStyleService {

    private WebClient webClient;

    public GeoServerStyleService() {
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
                .build();
    }

    public void editStyle(String styleName, String fill, String stroke) {
        String styleXml = "<NamedLayer>\n" +
                "    <Name>" + styleName + "</Name>\n" +
                "    <UserStyle>\n" +
                "      <Title>A dark yellow polygon style</Title>\n" +
                "      <FeatureTypeStyle>\n" +
                "        <Rule>\n" +
                "          <Title>dark yellow polygon</Title>\n" +
                "          <PolygonSymbolizer>\n" +
                "            <Fill>\n" +
                "              <CssParameter name=\"fill\">" + fill + "</CssParameter>\n" +
                "            </Fill>\n" +
                "            <Stroke>\n" +
                "              <CssParameter name=\"stroke\">" + stroke + "</CssParameter>\n" +
                "              <CssParameter name=\"stroke-width\">0.5</CssParameter>\n" +
                "            </Stroke>\n" +
                "          </PolygonSymbolizer>\n" +
                "        </Rule>\n" +
                "      </FeatureTypeStyle>\n" +
                "    </UserStyle>\n" +
                "  </NamedLayer>";

        webClient.post()
                .uri("styles/" + styleName + ".xml")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(styleXml))
                .retrieve()
                .toBodilessEntity()
                .block();
    }
}
```

I tried run code on http://localhost:8010/styles/point on the page and I have Whitelabel error and in postman I have an error 400 Bad Request. I don`t know what I can try

Comment: Your Java object `StyleRequest` in no-way matches the XML you are sending. There is thus no way it will map to that.

Comment: What should I do instead?

Comment: Create an object that matches your XML structure (and includes mapping annations from JAXB or Jackson XML), or receive the plain XML as a string and use XPath to extract what you need.

Comment: So i Have to create in StyleRequest all the variables that comes from my style point in geo?

<NamedLayer>
<Name>Point</Name>
<UserStyle>
<Title>Red Square point</Title>
<Abstract></Abstract>
<FeatureTypeStyle>
<Rule>
<Name>Rule 1</Name>
<Title>Red Square point</Title>
<Abstract>A red fill with 6 pixels size</Abstract>
<PointSymbolizer>
<Graphic>
<Mark>
<WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
<Fill>
<CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
</Fill>
</Mark>
<Size>6</Size>
</Graphic>
</PointSymbolizer>
</Rule>
</FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>

Comment: Don't post xml in the comments as that is totally unreadable. But yes you have to create a java representation from the XML **or** receive the XML as a `String` and use something like XPath or DOM to manually parse it and retrieve what you want.

Comment: Okay thank You. I had to send it like that because it was too long for comment. So I deleted spaces. Sorry for that. I will try the second method first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254534/discussion-between-piterek237-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two** steps to creating a new style via the REST API,

> You can create a new style on the server in two ways. In the first way, the creation is done in two steps: the style entry is created in the catalog, and then the style content is uploaded

So you need to do a POST to `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles`
with a body of:

```
<style><name>roads_style</name><filename>roads.sld</filename></style>
```

to create the style entry, and then a PUT to `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles/roads_style` - where the last element matches the name in the body above, with a content-type of `application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml` and a body containing the actual SLD (XML). If you want to change the style then you just repeat this step with the new SLD file.

See the [manual for examples](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/styles.html#creating-a-style)

Comment: Thanks! But I have one more question. If I want to run POST I should do it by adress like for example "http://localhost:8010/doPost" with @PostMapping("/doPost") or via postman?

Comment: It doesn't really matter how you do it - I use `curl` but java or python would work just as well

Comment: Then is my code below correct?

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this?

```
@Component
public class GeoServerClient {

RestTemplate rest;
String url;

@Autowired
public GeoServerClient(RestTemplate rest, @Value("${geo.url}") String url) {
this.rest= rest;
this.url= url;
}

public void createNewStyle() {
String createStyleUrl = geoserverUrl + "/rest/styles";
String xmlBody = "<style><name>roads_style</name><filename>roads.sld</filename>                    
</style>";

HttpHeaders head= new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

HttpEntity<String> request= new HttpEntity<>(xmlBody, headers);
}
}
```

Comment: That will complete step one - provided all your styles are called `roads_style`

Comment: @IanTurton I have a question. Cause in rest http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest/styles/point.html i have on this page the file to dowload with name default_point.sld which is geoserver style. Do You maybe know how to get into this style with help of GET Method to display it on screen?